# MySql query suddenly became very slow after a while

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a program that reads a set of entries from a database, performs some set of operations on these entries, and updates them in the database, the select query is pretty straight forward, It just selects the oldest updated top 200 entries.
The query also ignores any entries that were marked as "Deleted".

Now the weird thing is that query was running perfectly fine for a couple of days, with execution time, not exceding 200ms, but all of a sudden the execution time jumped to over 15 seconds and stayed like that.

```
SELECT 
    `x`.`Id`, `x`.`InternalId`
FROM
    `my_entry` AS `x`
WHERE (`x`.`IsDeleted` <> TRUE OR `x`.`IsDeleted` IS NULL)
ORDER BY `x`.`UpdatedDate`
LIMIT 200;
```

Table structure:

```
Id int(11) AI PK 
InternalId varchar(30) 
UpdatedDate datetime
IsDeleted bit(1)
```

I also have a BTREE index on the UpdatedDate column

Any leads on this problem, or where should I be looking for more details?

Thanks

Comment: Share the `explain` execution plan and edit your post. like `explain select ...`

Comment: 1) `CREATE INDEX idx ON my_entry (IsDeleted, UpdatedDate)` 2) Replace `<> TRUE` with `= False` 3) Recommendation. Update `IsDeleted`, convert NULLs to False, then set its DEFAULT to False and define it as NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The way the query is written, and the way `IsDeleted` is implemented, make the use of any index on `IsDeleted` useless.  (Akina's comment explains h

If you have `INDEX(UpdatedDate)` then that index may help in the query.  (Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.)  But, if there are a lot of rows that fail that `IsDeleted` test, then it would have to scan a lot of rows to find 200.  This might be the answer to the sluggishness.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.